# How to pass String PackageName to PkgName under parseXML() and run XMLParser class as a new activity when click on list

Tags: java, android

**XMLHandler.java**

```
    package com.example.listapps;
    import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    String PermissionList = "";

    String Result = "";
    public String getResult() {
    return Result;
    }


    String[]Mypermission = {".READ_SMS",".SMS_SEND",".RECEIVE_SMS",".WRITE_SMS",".PROCESS_OUTGOING_CA","LL.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS",".READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS",".WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS",".READ_LOGS",".INSTALL_PACKAGES",".MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"};
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("uses-permission"))
    {
    PermissionList += attributes.getValue("name")+ " ";
    int MaliciousPer =0;
    String []permissions = PermissionList.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<Mypermission.length; i++)
      {
    for(int j=0; j<permissions.length; j++)
        {
    if(Mypermission[i].equals(permissions[j].substring(permissions[j].lastIndexOf("."))))
    { MaliciousPer++; }
        }
      }
    int PerCount = permissions.length;
    if( PerCount == 9 && MaliciousPer == 0){result = "Yes";}
    else{Result = "No";}
    }
    }
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
    package com.example.listapps;
    import java.io.Closeable;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class XMLParser extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xml_parser)// show String Result on layout
    parseXML();
    }

    public void parseXML() {
    try {
    String PkgName = PackageName;// PackageName want to pass from MainAciviy
    String input = PkgName + ".xml";
    InputSource inputSource = null;
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator +"Tools" + File.separator + input;
        FileInputStream xmlFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    inputSource = new InputSource(xmlFileInputStream);
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
    xr.parse(inputSource);
    String Result = myXMLHandler.getResult();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    ((Closeable) inputSource).close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
     import android.app.ListActivity;
     import android.app.ProgressDialog;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
     import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
     import android.os.AsyncTask;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.ListView;

     public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

     private PackageManager packageManager = null;
     private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
     private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;


     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     packageManager = getPackageManager();
     new LoadApplications().execute();
     }

     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
     {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  
      ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
      String PackageName = app.packageName;
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMLParser.class);
      intent.putExtra("PkgName", PackageName);//It is correct to pass value?
      startActivity(intent);
      }
      }
```

When I click on lists, I want to pass **String PackageName** to **PkgName** under **parseXML()** and run **XMLParser class** as a new activity. And I want to show Result **"Yes"** or **"No"** on new activity's layout. Please fixed this code for me. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're passing the `PackageName` value to the `XMLParser` through the intent:

```
intent.putExtra("PkgName", PackageName);
```

To access this value in the `XMLParser` activity, just change this line:

```
String PkgName = PackageName;
```

To:

```
String PkgName = getIntent().getStringExtra("PkgName");
```

Comment: @Titus- Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Titus- But how can I set String result for text view layout?

Comment: @Titus- Thank you so much again. It's work well and all ok. Just one I wanna know, when I press back it quit instead back to the list. Please help me.

Comment: @MaungMaung Try `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XMLParser.class);` instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMLParser.class);`. If this answer fixed your problem, don't forget to marked it as the accepted answer.